# Why does the switch statement run only the default and ignores the remaining conditions?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm writing an endpoint that returns all data from the database if a query is not provided but returns only the data that meets the query condition if a query is provided

```
    try {
      const { origin, destination } = req.query;
      switch (req.query) {
        case { origin }: {
          const data = await Trips.tripModel().select('*', `WHERE origin='${origin}'`);
          if (!data[0]) return nullResponse(res, 'No trips available from here');
          return successResponse(res, 200, data);
        }

        case { destination }: {
          const data = await Trips.tripModel().select('*', `WHERE destination='${destination}'`);
          if (!data[0]) return nullResponse(res, 'No trips available to this destination');
          return successResponse(res, 200, data);
        }

        default: {
          const data = await Trips.tripModel().select('*');
          if (!data[0]) return nullResponse(res, 'No trips available');
          return successResponse(res, 200, data);
        }
      }
  }
```

If a query is provided on postman i.e `/api/trips?origin=london`, it's supposed to return only the data that meets the condition `origin = london` but instead, it returns all data which is the default condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ origin }` creates a new object with a single property. This is not strict equal to the `req.query`, the value for comparing.

You need values who are comparable in a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). In this case you could take a strange comparison with `false`, assuming the values have either a truthy value or `undefined`.

```
 switch (false) {
    case !origin: {
      const data = await Trips.tripModel().select('*', `WHERE origin='${origin}'`);
      if (!data[0]) return nullResponse(res, 'No trips available from here');
      return successResponse(res, 200, data);
    }

    case !destination: {
      const data = await Trips.tripModel().select('*', `WHERE destination='${destination}'`);
      if (!data[0]) return nullResponse(res, 'No trips available to this destination');
      return successResponse(res, 200, data);
    }
}
```